# Capistrano fails when trying to deploy Rails asset manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app that has worked successfully before, but Capistrano is barfing during deployment. I don't believe I've changed anything other than changing the Rails app code itself and updating some gems (i.e. the deploy.rb file is identical to a once-working setup.)

Here's the line it appears to fail on:

```
executing "cp -- /u/apps/myapp/shared/assets/manifest.yml /u/apps/myapp/releases/unable/assets_manifest.yml"
```

Notice how the directory it's trying to copy to is called `unable`. It's like it can't get the new release name/date or something? And yet earlier it executes this without error:

```
executing "cd -- /u/apps/myapp/releases/20130507041223 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
```

The remainder of the interesting output is this:

```
** cp: cannot create regular file `/u/apps/myapp/releases/unable/assets_manifest.yml'
** No such file or directory
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cp -- /u/apps/myapp/shared/assets/manifest.yml /u/apps/myapp/releases/unable/assets_manifest.yml'"
```

**UPDATE:** This appears to be a bug in Capistrano 2.15.4. Downgrading to version 2.14.2 fixed the problem. I've detailed the bug here:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/468

Comment: Please answer you own question. It's still on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Capistrano 2.15.4. Downgrading to version 2.14.2 fixes the problem. See https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/468

Comment: i fixed issue by setting capistrano-rails to 1.1.3 and capistrano at 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with 2.15.4.  It was because I had changed my hostname to something invalid - everytime i su'd it told me 'unable to resolve host ' which this version of cap was picking up for some reason.  Setting the hostname back to the proper setting seems to have sorted it.